# Find all polynomial such for $x\in Z$ then $f(x)\in Z$

Tags: polynomials

> Find all polynomials $f(x)$ such that $\deg(f)=4$ and such for all $x\in Z$ then $f(x)\in Z$.

My try: since $f(x)=x^4$ is such it

because $$x\in Z\Longrightarrow x^4\in Z$$
and 
$$f(x)=a_{4}x^4+a_{3}x^3+a_{2}x^2+a_{1}x+a_{0},~~~~~~~~~~~~~~a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}\in Z$$
is such it and have other form? Thank you.

Comment: Consider the polynomials $\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-k+1)}{k!}$. All integer linear combinations of these have the desired property, and that's it. In the case degree $4$, we have a positive coefficient term with $k=4$, and lower degree terms.

Comment: oh,Thank you,But this have other form? Thank you

Comment: What is $Z$? Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The result mentioned in the above comment is the only general characterization of the the general polynomials that are integers at integers that I know. Probably a proof has appeared on MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Write $\displaystyle\ f(x) = c_0 + c_1 {x \choose 1} + \cdots + c_4 {x \choose 4},\ $ possible since $\displaystyle {x\choose k}\,$ has degree $k$. Then

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(0) &=& c_0 \\ f(1) &=& c_0 + {1\choose 1} c_1 \\ f(2) &=& c_0 + {2\choose 1} c_1 + {2\choose 2} c_2 \\ f(3) &=& c_0 + {3\choose 1} c_1 + {3\choose 2} c_2 + {3\choose 3} c_3 \\ f(4) &=& c_0 + {4\choose 1}c_1 + {4\choose 2}c_2 + {4\choose 3} c_3 + {4\choose 4} c_4 \end{eqnarray}$$

Successively solving the above *triangular* system for $\,c_0,\ c_1,\ c_2,\ldots$ shows that all $\,c_i\in \Bbb Z$, since all $f(i), {j\choose k}\in \Bbb Z\,$ and each linear equation in $\,c_i\,$ is *monic*, i.e. has lead coef $= {i\choose i} = 1.\,$  Conversely, if all $c_i\in \Bbb Z$ then $f(n)\in \Bbb Z$ since all ${x \choose i}$ are integer valued.

Thus $f(x)$ is integer-valued $\iff$ its coefficients in a binomial basis are all integers.

Clearly the same proof works for polynomial of any degree. This is a well-known [result of Polya and Ostrowski.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/642007/242)

Comment: oh,Nice,so we can have this relsut: if $f(x)$ is real polynomial of the degerr is $n$,such as $f(0),f(1),\cdots,f(n)$ is integer,then $f(x)\in Z,\forall x\in Z$

Comment: This is essentially a proof by Newton interpolation, for the sample points $0,1,2,3,4$, if one want an official name for the method.